# FlowRouter not redirecting calling its action in onLogout

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, flow-router

On the client side, when I implement `Accounts.onLogout` I say that it should redirect to the root directory using `FlowRouter.go('root');` and also tried with `FlowRouter.go('/');`. However it seems that it doesn't redirect properly.

Curiously, if I use a timeout (something I don't like) it works, and if I redirect to root and then do a `FlowRouter.reload();` it doesn't change the address bar (actually it changes to root and quickly changes to where it was).

Is the user still logged in when `onLogout` is called?

What would be the best approach?

```
Accounts.onLogout(() => {
        // setTimeout(() => {FlowRouter.go('/');}, 3000); this way works
        FlowRouter.go('/'); // this way changes the address bar but doesn't rerender.
        // FlowRouter.reload(); adding this, keeps the address bar where it was, in my case in /panel
})
```

Comment: Maybe there is a trigger on a route interfering with the redirect?

Comment: What kind of trigger? How do I check it?

Comment: See https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router/blob/master/README.md#triggers

Comment: @Jankapunkt I'm not using any trigger. Actually, right now my router is so simple that it has only two routes. One for logged in users, and another one for non-logged in users.